# Serving STATIC FILES in development and Amazon S3 together

Tags: amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I would like to server static files from Amazon S3 and local server?

also I don't know how to setup `MEDIA_URL` `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT`

Context:

I am serving my static files from `Amazon S3` using `django-boto` and my `settings/base.py` are:

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'assets'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'

STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'

MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

My `custom_storages.py` file content is:

```
from django.conf import settings
# from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage


class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

And all of this is working fine. 
When I execute `collectstatic` my static files are being uploaded to my bucket in Amazon S3.

The problem I have is that every time I make a change in my `css` or `js` files, I need to do the `collectstatic` command.

How can I setup my project (settings) to serve my static files from S3 and my django in a local server together?

I have a `settings/development.py` file in which I am overriding the following settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'assets'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = MEDIAFILES_LOCATION

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

And my `urls.py` main file I have this condition:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```